# How to optimize $ \inf_{\epsilon \geq 0} \{\epsilon + \frac{r\sqrt{2B}}{n}\}$ subject to $B \leq C\epsilon^{-1/\alpha}$?

Tags: optimization

Curious about how to solve this optimization problem, anyone has some thoughts about this?
$$ \inf_{\epsilon \geq 0} \{\epsilon + \frac{r\sqrt{2B}}{n}\}$$
$$B \leq C\epsilon^{-1/\alpha}$$

Comment: What variables are you optimising over?

Comment: @copper.hat over $$\epsilon$$

Comment: $B \le C \epsilon^{- {1 \over \alpha}} $ is equivalent to $\epsilon \le ({C \over B})^\alpha$. Hence the answer is ${r \sqrt{2B} \over n}$.